# Django easy-thumbnails MAX SIZE

Tags: python, django, django-apps, django-models

is there a way to set a max size for the images uploaded in my django app using [easy-thumbnails](https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails) app?

In the settings list I don't see anything about it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To cap file size, you might want to do it in the webserver, rather than in Django.

Alternatively, you can [specify a custom file handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#writing-custom-upload-handlers), with which you can raise an error if the file is too big:

```
from django.core.files.uploadhandler import TemporaryFileUploadHandler, StopUpload

class SizeLimitUploadHandler(TemporaryFileUploadHandler):
    def new_file(self, field_name, file_name, content_type, content_length, charset):
        if content_length > MAX_FILE_SIZE:
            raise StopUpload(True)
```

Though this will cause a connection reset error in order to stop processing the large file.

If you want to cap *image* size, you can resize the image before it is saved as stated in the readme:

> By passing a `resize_source` argument to the `ThumbnailerImageField`, you can resize the source image before it is saved:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    avatar = ThumbnailerImageField(
        upload_to='avatars',
        resize_source=dict(size=(50, 50), crop='smart'),
    )
```

Comment: Sorry, I mean the file size, not size as resolution. For example max size = 2MB.

Comment: -1 FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE controls the maximum size of an uploaded file before it is written to disk *NOT* the maximum size of an uploaded file.

Comment: @hekevintran Thanks, I must have read the docs wrong when I first answered this question. I updated my answer to mention / show other ways of stopping the file upload; comments?